# Does a sitemap need to contain linked static pages?

Tags: php, html, xml, seo, sitemap

I want to generate a sitemap for my dynamic content. Do I need to also include the static pages which are already linked throughout my site? I want to just make a script which will query my inventory and then generate sitemap based on that.

Want to do it with PHP.

After submitting the sitemap, I'm hoping google will still find my static pages even if they are not listed in the sitemap!

Thank you

-D

Comment: A sitemap should include ALL pages on your site. What have you tried?

Comment: if its linked google will find it. I dont bother with site maps any more, google seems to work just fine with out one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are linked then Google will find them, however, personally I like to include all of my pages (static and dynamic) in my sitemap. This just ensures that Google can see everything.

There are several websites you can use to generate sitemaps, this is one that I like:

http://www.web-site-map.com/index.php

You can then add to the sitemap, any pages that are not linked to from the submitted document.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

Google **DOES** index any pages that are linked within your site, however, a sitemap makes this process more efficient and effective. At the end of the day, it is up to you whether or not you use one. As they are so easy to build, I don't see why you wouldn't as it will not damage your SEO, it will only help it, if anything.

The important thing to note is that any pages that are not linked, Google (and any other crawlers), will not find! This is where sitemaps are very useful.

To summarize, sitemaps are not absolutely necessary, but they are strongly recommend!

Comment: so that sites crawls your site to make a sitemap - which is how the google bot works anyway.

Comment: @Dagon Yes that is true, but it produces the sitemap so you can store it locally on the server and then submit it to Google :-) Just makes it easier, and allows you to specify which pages to submit to Google

Comment: this doesn't answer my question though. I want to know if google will make their own sitemap and include pages I haven't included in my sitemap.

Comment: @DaveFes again, yes, if its linked google will find it.

Comment: @Dagon I agree to a certain degree as Google does indeed index the pages on your site as long as they are linked to. However, using sitemaps makes the indexing much more efficient (especially for larger sites)

Comment: @DaveFes See my updated answer. Google does not create its own sitemap, it creates an index of your websites pages. This is similar to its own sitemap, but it will only contain what it sees (as in the pages that are linked to). Google cannot see your web directory, it can only see the HTML on your linked pages. Just by having a file on the site does not mean Google will see it. Sitemaps just allow Google to crawl and index your site more efficiently and intelligently, as they are so simple to build, what is the harm in doing it??